# Join results in parent child query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I was able to do "has_child" query and it worked well. But  i want to see the matching children also per parent. Is this possible suing aggregations , or is there a better way ?

Comment: please post a few of the work you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the experimental [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) feature. For example:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "has_child" : {
            "type" : "comment",
            "query": { ... },
            "inner_hits" : {} 
        }
    }
}
```

Will add an inner_hits property to each returned hit. You can pass extra options to inner_hits, for example to disable fetching of _source if you only need the id